# How to add the user id to the button interaction?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am working on a Discord bot and I am trying to get the buttons to work only for the user who used the command.

I'm sorry if I sound dumb, but I don't know how to explain it correctly.

What I have so far, is the command **test** which sends a message in the channel, with 2 buttons attached to it, and what I want, is to attach the user's ID to the buttons.

.setCustomId(`button1-${message.author.id}`)

This actually works if all the code is in one file. But it doesn't work if I split the code for the buttons.

I tried adding -${interaction.user.id} to the button name, but it doesn't work, as it gives me "interaction is not defined".

```
module.exports = {
  data: {
    name: `button1`
  },
  async execute (interaction, client) {

  interaction.channel.send({ content: "This button works!"})

    
  }
}
```

Is there any way to add the user's id to the button name?

Comment: Where's your file which is you created button in?

Comment: The button is in the test command file. Here is the code:
```if(message.content.startsWith(PREFIX + "test")) {

const row = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
   new MessageButton()
   .setLabel("✔")
   .setStyle("PRIMARY")
   .setCustomId(`button1-${message.author.id}`),

  new MessageButton()
   .setLabel("✔")
   .setStyle("SECONDARY")
   .setCustomId(`button2-${message.author.id}`)

 )

  message.reply({ content: "Hello", components: [ row ] })
}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you out here. Any time an application command is used, that message has an element to identify who sent it `interaction.message.interaction.user.id` which is the user id of the person who sent the command.

However in your use, you are using a message, which is fine and it will still work as a message has an element to specify who is being replied to `interaction.message.mentions.users` so to put that into use for you, try the below code. You won't need to add the users id to the button code.

```js
if (message.content.startsWith(PREFIX + "test")) {
    const row = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
        new MessageButton()
            .setLabel("✔")
            .setStyle("PRIMARY")
            .setCustomId(`button1`),
        new MessageButton()
            .setLabel("✔")
            .setStyle("SECONDARY")
            .setCustomId(`button2`),
    );
    message.reply({
        content: "Hello",
        components: [row],
    });
}
```

The below section is part of your `interactionCreate` code if part of the main bot.js file

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (interaction.isButton()) {
        const buttonID = interaction.customId;
        if (buttonID === 'button1') {
            if (interaction.message.mentions.users.get(interaction.user.id)) {
                interaction.channel.send({
                    content: "This button works!",
                });
                // This is the sender of the command
                console.log(true);
            } else {
                // This is not the sender
                console.log(false);
                return;
            }
        } else if (buttonID === 'button2') {
            if (interaction.message.mentions.users.get(interaction.user.id)) {
                interaction.channel.send({
                    content: "This button works!",
                });
                console.log(true);
            } else {
                // This is not the sender
                console.log(false);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

In the event you have your `interactionCreate` command as a separate file, the code would look like this

```js
module.exports = {
    data: {
        name: `interactionCreate`,
    },
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        const buttonID = interaction.customId;
        if (buttonID === 'button1') {
            if (interaction.message.mentions.users.get(interaction.user.id)) {
                interaction.channel.send({
                    content: "This button works!",
                });
                // This is the sender of the command
                console.log(true);
            } else {
                // This is not the sender
                console.log(false);
                return;
            }
        } else if (buttonID === 'button2') {
            if (interaction.message.mentions.users.get(interaction.user.id)) {
                interaction.channel.send({
                    content: "This button works!",
                });
                console.log(true);
            } else {
                // This is not the sender
                console.log(false);
                return;
            }
        }
    },
};
```